# Using boost IOStreams with std::ostream_iterator

Tags: c++, boost, boost-iostreams, istream-iterator

I tried to use an array-device based stream and wantet to pass the stream to `std::ostream_iterator` or `std::istream_iterator`, but unfortunately, I get a compilation error with gcc 4.3.5.

Boost::IOStreams documentation states that the `io::stream` is either derived from `std::basic_istream` or `std::basic_ostream` or both (`std::basic_iostream`) dependent on the underlying device category. array device has seekable category, so I'd expect io::stream to derive from `std::basic_iostream` and be compatible with `std::ostream_iterator` or `std::istream_iterator`. But I unfortunately get a compilation error.

Here is the code snippet:

```
namespace io=boost::io;

typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef io::basic_array<byte>  array_device;
typedef io::stream<array_device> array_stream;

byte my_buffer[256]={};

array_stream  ios_(my_buffer); 

std::istream_iterator<byte> in(ios_);
```

And the last line results in the error stating:

```
src/my_file.cpp: In member function 'void my_test_class::ctor::test_method()':
src/my_file.cpp:86: error: no matching function for call to 
'std::istream_iterator<unsigned char, char, std::char_traits<char>, int>::istream_iterator(my_test_class::<unnamed>::array_stream&)'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not supplying enough template arguments for `std::istream_iterator` -- the second argument is the underlying character type of the stream, which defaults to `char`, but the underlying character type of your stream is `byte` (`unsigned char`).

Changing

```cpp
std::istream_iterator<byte> in(ios_);
```

to

```cpp
std::istream_iterator<byte, byte> in(ios_);
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Many thanks for your help! I somehow overlooked that!